# Variables and escaping in RPM SPEC file macros?

Tags: linux, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I want to define a macro that will replace some placeholders in makefiles and systemd unit files with the results of RPM variables (macros). However, I don't know if the way expansion works will make the following behave correctly:

`%define repl_vars() (sed -e "s:\${LIBEXECDIR}:%{_libexecdir}:g" -e "s:\${LOCALSTATEDIR}:%{_localstatedir}:g" -e "s:\${SYSCONFIGDIR}:%{_sysconfdir}:g" %{1} > %{1}.new && mv %{1}.new %{1})`

Where the capitalized `${...}` are the placeholders to be replaced with the actual paths held by the standard RPM variables (macros).

Also, escaping the `$` of the placeholders with `\` works in Bash and stuff I put in the `%install` section of the SPEC file, but is that still valid in a macro? And is the `%{1}` valid, as I've never seen an example -- and if not, how do I concatenate `.new` to `%1`?

If this is wrong, how do I do it?

Comment: If you use single-quoted strings you don't need to escape `$` in shell strings.

Comment: Are those `sed` commands just commands that you want to use in `%install`? You will use `%repl_vars some_file` in the `%install` section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr Yes, that looks basically correct to me. See http://www.rpm.org/wiki/PackagerDocs/Macros for some (somewhat outdated but still largely relevant) documentation.

Macros that are to be expanded in a shell context in a spec file just want to expand to the literal lines that you would write in the spec file section manually.

So assuming you want something to the effect of:

```
%install
....
sed -e 's:${LIBEXECDIR}:%{_libexecdir}:g' -e 's:${LOCALSTATEDIR}:%{_localstatedir}:g' -e 's:${SYSCONFIGDIR}:%{_sysconfdir}:g' 'some_file' > 'some_file.new' && mv 'some_file.new' 'some_file'
....
```

And you want to call your macro as `%repl_vars some_file` then you want a macro roughly like this:

```
%define repl_vars() sed -e 's:${LIBEXECDIR}:%{_libexecdir}:g' -e 's:${LOCALSTATEDIR}:%{_localstatedir}:g' -e 's:${SYSCONFIGDIR}:%{_sysconfdir}:g' '%{1}' > '%{1}.new' && mv '%{1}.new' '%{1}'
```

Notice I switched to single quotes instead of double quotes to avoid `$` from being evaluated and needing to be escaped. I also dropped the wrapping `()` because this didn't seem to need the forced sub-shell.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'll go with.